# SqlBinder does not allow to declare a table variable

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I noticed that **SqlBinder** C# library erases table variable when calling `.GetSql()`.

The SQL in the query string:

```
DECLARE @LOCAL_TABLEVARIABLE TABLE
(
    ColumnName BIGINT
);
```

The SQL after `.GetSql()` call:

```
DECLARE TABLE
(
    ColumnName BIGINT
);
```

Is there any way to declare and use table variable in SqlBinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to call:

```
.DefineVariable("LOCAL_TABLEVARIABLE", "@LOCAL_TABLEVARIABLE");
```